# Pass parameter in React Url to get relative data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I created a express api where when we pass parameter to url say localhost:8000/data?music=rock it gives me data associated with it and if i pass say localhost:8000/data?music=rap and gives me data associated with it....P.S. there are many genre of music classical and so on and data associated with it.

**Express api**:: connected to mongoose where I **scraped** a data and stored in mongodb from where it feteches the data

```
app.get('/data'.(res,req)=>{
    count music = req.query.music
    collection.find({"music":music},(err,result)=>{
        if(err):
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(docs);
            res.send(docs);
        }
    });
});
```

**React JS::**::

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {apiResponse:"",genre:""};
  }
  async callAPI(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const url = `http://localhost:8000/data?music=${e.target.value}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response);
    const textResponse = response.text();
    console.log(textResponse);
    this.setState({apiResponse:textResponse});
  }

  render() {
    const {apiResponse} = this.state;
    console.log(apiResponse);

    return (
      <>
        <select name="continent" id="continent" onClick={e=>this.callAPI(e)}>
          <option value=" ">--Please choose an option--</option>
          <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
          <option value="North America">North America</option>
        </select>
        {apiResponse && <h1>{apiResponse.title}</h1>}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now i connected my express api with react but as you can see i have provided static path as

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/data?music=Rock")
```

to get the data associated with rock music.

But I want react to fetch different genre of music dynamically from API  without using a static path to fetch data. like react port:: localhost:3000/music=rock and it gives me data of rock music or classical and it gives me data of that.

Can anyone from community guide me on what method can be used or any article? Will be really appreciated. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `select` element to trigger an `onChange` event to fetch `data` from the user. Here, I replaced the `url` with `template literals`. After the `fetch` is complete and `apiResponse` is set, you can then `map` the data in the `return` block.

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sun-5cr6r?file=/src/App.js).

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: "", genre: "" };
  }

  async callAPI(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  const url = `http://localhost:8000/data?music=${e.target.value}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(response);
  const textResponse = response.text();
  console.log(textResponse);
  this.setState({ apiResponse: textResponse });
}


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <select name="genre" id="genre" onChange={e => this.callAPI(e)}>
          <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
          <option value="Rap">Rap</option>
          <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
        </select>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How to redirect the react localhost to fetch from say http://localhost:8000/data?music=rap and get data associated with it.....because while running it just selects the options and nothing

Comment: I have also updated the `sandbox` with a suitable example.

Comment: I've edited my code as per solution by you but it's not fetching the api's data....nothing on console is comming. Can you please have a look at the code?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked there was some error in Node js part because  of which data was not comming. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis for the request and set the params, in this case, the music

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/data', {
    params: {
      music: 'rap'
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

You can read more about axis [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: But over here you have defined the genre of music as rap but i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: the param `music` is a variable and could be whatever you wan, if you want to get it from an input for example, you could create the input like:

`<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />` 

And pass this value to the music param.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a controlled input field for music and use `this.state.music` in the fetch URL

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components